# Oracle - Alias no Case

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Como posso colocar um alias no nome da coluna em um CASE?

```
CASE atu.cod_situacao_matricula "Alias"
WHEN 2 THEN 'Matriculado'

CASE atu.cod_situacao_matricula as Alias
WHEN 2 THEN 'Matriculado'
```

Ambos dão erro "palavra-chave FROM não localizada onde esperado" e não adianta nem faz sentido colocar vírgula

Sem o alias o nome da coluna sai [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca o alias depois do 'end'

```
CASE atu.cod_situacao_matricula 
WHEN 2 THEN 'Matriculado'

WHEN 3 THEN 'Outro'
END as Teste
```

Comment: obrigada, é isso mesmo